# Add custom data to laravel log

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5

I want for a certain Laravel Job class to change the behaviour of the logging system. This is how my logs look right now:

```
[2018-08-22 08:31:24] production.INFO: [do-harvester-job]
[template: 598 - theme: 2592]Doing tasks
```

This is achieved by the following code:

```
\Log::info("{$this->harvester_job->log_prefix()}Doing tasks");
```

The problem is that I have a lot of log calls like this one and it gets cumbersome to always add the call to the `log_prefix` method.

Is there any way of prepending that info to the log without having to concatenate it inside the log call?

Comment: You can always write up your own Log class with methods that prefix stuff you want. Extend the provided Log class, add some methods and just change the calls.

Comment: Thanks @Loek that's exactly what I did, dont know why I got stuck in the mindset that it has to be done thru the laravel framework somehow. I have created a class called HarvesterLog, and I have overwritten the logging methods

Comment: It happens to everyone :) glad to help!

Answer (score -2):

If you are facing problems in displaying the class data inside log file then you can use json_encode($className->fetchAllData()).

Comment: Nice and all, but unrelated to OPs question.